# Differentiate Gibbs free energy maybe by using chain rule?

Tags: derivatives, education, differential, chain-rule

I found in a book this function $ G(P,T,n_1,...) $ and its differential:

$$ dG = \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial P} \right)_{T, n_1,...} dt +
\left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial T} \right)_{P, n_1,...} dt  +...$$

The pedices mean that those variables are considered constants.

Can you tell me how can I get the above result please?

I know only that if I have the function $ f(x,y) $, the differential is:

$$ df = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) dx +
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) dy $$

but I think that this is another story (Taylor stuff).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This would probabaly have a better chance of getting a good answer at [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Also I think your equation should be $$ d G = \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial P} \right)_{\dots} d P + \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial T} \right)_{\dots} d T + \cdots $$ ($d P$ and $d T$ instead of $d t$).

Comment: Hello @CarlosEsparza, thank you for your suggestion...I think that it is only math stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, that is the same story! The Gibbs free energy is a thermodynamic potential which is a function of $T,p,N_{1},...,N_{k}$, where $T$ is the temperature of the system, $p$ is its pressure and $N_{1},...,N_{k}$ are the number of particles of each constituent of the system. For simplicity, let us consider $k=1$ and $N_{1} \equiv N$. Then $G = G(T,p,N)$. Now, by your definition of a differential, we have:

$$
dG =
\bigg{(}\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\bigg{)}dT +
\bigg{(}\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\bigg{)}dp +
\bigg{(}\frac{\partial G}{\partial N}\bigg{)}dN
$$